# How to make database connection from different website

Tags: php, mysql, database, server, hosting

I have a database in a website called booksiders.com and then I have a new website called kryptotech.co.in in which i am looking to use the database of the first website. So how can connect with the database which exists on another hosting server.

This is the code i am using in kryptotech.co.in for connecting to the database of booksiders.com from kryptotech.co.in which is hosted on another server.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("booksiders.com","bookside","******");

if(!mysql_select_db("bookside_kryptoDB",$con))
    echo "Unable to connect to database";


?>
```

Please tell me what hostname should be used for doing this.

Comment: Is the mysql server on the other host configured to allow connections directly from outside? If not, then you cannot connect directly to it. You may have to build an interim api using php (or any other server side technology) that receives your requests via http, performs the database actions on the localhost and returns the results to the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to allow your server IP in allow remote host access list on remote server and ask them to allow port 3306 in their firewall so that you can connect mysql databases from your hosting server.

Comment: Is it truly a good practice to allow remote access to a database of a web application? I doubt it...